# Whats being compared in this line of code?

Tags: javascript, if-statement

What does the space between ops[i] and [calc[j]] mean? Whats being compared.

```
if (ops[i][calc[j]]) {
            currentOp = ops[i][calc[j]];
```

Comment: This is a 2D Array, and the values might be something like ops[1][1]. Nothing is being compared, it is just checked, if the value exists.

Comment: What space are you referring to?

Comment: ops[i]         here        [calc[j]]

Comment: the space is irrelevant (and non-existent in the code you posted)

Comment: `if the value exists` - not quite right, because if the value at that position is `0`, `'0'`, `''`, `null`, `undefined` or `false` (I probably missed something), it is considered "falsey", so the assignment to currentOp will NOT take place, whereas other values are "truthy" and the assignment to `currentOp` will take place

Answer (score 0):

In this condition, the value isn't *compared*, it's just checked to be true-ish.

For example, these values are true-ish:

- `"hello"`
- `1`
- `234`
- `{}`
- `true` (of course)

On the opposite, these values aren't:

- `0`
- `null`
- `false` (of course)
- `undefined`

So, if you do:

```
if (true) { console.log('This code will be run') }
if (234) { console.log('This one too!') }

if (0) { console.log('But this one won\'t') }
```

A good way to know if a value is true-ish is to put a double `!` before it:

```
console.log(!!0) // -> false
console.log(!!'hello') // -> true
```

It works because `!` inverse the value: if it's a true-ish value, it transforms it to the **actual** `false` and vice-versa. And, if you invert something twice, you get what you had first.

---

Now, the value that is checked to be true-ish is located in a 2D array, like @user1767754 said. Have a look at this:

```
const myArray = [
    [1, 2, 3, 4],
    [5, 6, 7, 8],
    [9, 10, 11, 12]
]
```

How do access the `7`? First, you get its containing array, which is the second: `myArray[1]`. Once you got this, you just have to select the `7` like you would do normally: `myArray[1][2]`.

You can see this as a table. First, you select the row (`1`), and then the column (`2`).

But you can make 3D arrays, 4D ones, it's unlimited.

But, what if the value `2` is located in another array, called, say `indices`, like this:

```
const indices = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Well, you can do `myArray[1][indices[1]]` to access the `7`.

---

Then, the space between the brackets does not matter (`something[1] [2]` is the same as `something[1][2]`).

Hopefully, it will have helped you a bit to understand the code you posted in your question.